# MUI Error: One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a website in MUI, and for that, I made a custom `Layout` component, where I add app bars, drawers etc. Here, I needed to push my content down, so I made a class called `toolbar` and applied it. But I am getting the error:

```cs
Material-UI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

Here is my code, and as you can see, I am using a `ThemeProvider`. Can you help me?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import Video from "./pages/Video";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Layout>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/video" element={<Video />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Layout.jsx`

```
import Header from "./Header";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({ toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar }));

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Box className={classes.toolbar}></Box>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Header.jsx`

```
import {
  AppBar,
  Box,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import { orange } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import ClickableAvatar from "./ClickableAvatar";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Header() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchor);
  const openMenu = (e) => setAnchor(e.currentTarget);
  const closeMenu = () => setAnchor(null);
  const selectValue = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    setValue(e.target.innerText);
  };
  const classes = {
    logo: {
      width: 104,
    },
    avatar: {
      backgroundColor: orange[500],
    },
    menu: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
  };

  const displayName = "AtharvNadkarni";
  const displayNameToKebabCase = (displayName) =>
    displayName.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-");
  const displayNameHash = (displayName) =>
    Buffer.from(displayName).toString("base64");

  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar sx={classes.menu}>
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/funlurnwordmark.png" style={classes.logo} />
        </a>
        <ClickableAvatar
          src={`https://api.dicebear.com/7.x/pixel-art/svg?seed=${displayName}`}
          sx={classes.avatar}
          fallbackText={displayName
            .split(" ")
            .map((name) => name[0])
            .join("")}
          openMenuCallback={openMenu}
        >
          <Menu anchorEl={anchor} open={open} onClose={closeMenu}>
            <MenuItem onClick={selectValue}>A</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={selectValue}>B</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={selectValue}>C</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </ClickableAvatar>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am running into the same issue. While migrating from react-scripts to Vite I updated plenty of libraries, but nothing major - still ran into this issue...